# Creating a Ember.js component with bootstrap-select, Ember adding <!----> to DOM elements

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components

I'm trying to wrap [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) in a component as part of my effort to learn and understand Ember.js. However, I'm running into an issue where it looks like Ember interferes with the DOM elements created by the plugin.

When calling the plugin with `.selectpicker()` on didInsertElement (or even through the Ember run loop), it generates/modifies the DOM for the dropdown incorrectly. The text inside of the `<options>` are converted into `<!---->`, which has something to do with Glimmer AFAIK.

```
//compontents/opportunity-select.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    class: 'selectpicker',
    selectedOpportunityId: null,
    didInsertElement: function(){
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => this.$().selectpicker());
    }
});
```

```
//templates/components/opportunity-select.hbs

{{#each opportunities as |opportunity|}}
  <option>
        {{opportunity.name}}
  </option>
{{/each}}
```

The DOM elements in question - note the `<!---->` which appears in place of the text.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu open" ><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" >
        <li data-original-index="0">
            <a tabindex="0" >
                <span class="text">
                    <!---->
              </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-original-index="1">
            <a tabindex="1">
                <span class="text">
                    <!---->
              </span>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<select>` that gets generated by Ember without `bootstrap-select`:

```
<select id="ember592" class="ember-view">  <option>
        Opportunity 0
  </option>
  <option>
        Opportunity 1
  </option>
  <option>
        Opportunity 2
  </option>
</select>
```

Once again, this works perfectly fine when done from the console. Any ideas? I'm at wit's end here.

UPDATE: Just to show that is works to the point of the opportunities actually being pulled in and everything - just the text in the dropdown that's generated by bootstrap-select is blank. It still is selectable though. Ember Twiddle here: http://ember-twiddle.com/5637ed5974e5d1e79906 (i can't get selectpicker to actually work in Ember Twiddle, but you'll see that the opps gets pulled through and everything)

[image: Dropdown works, opportunties are present, but text is missing]

Comment: That means that `opportunities` is empty, are you passing anything to the property?

Comment: Looks like opportunities are there - I've added the `<select>` that gets generated to my question. Also, it works fine when I call $('select#ember592').selectpicker() from the console.

Comment: Any chance you can replicate this in an ember-twiddle

Comment: @Kitler I've created a Twiddle here: http://ember-twiddle.com/5637ed5974e5d1e79906 - however, I can't get selectpicker to work in Twiddle. It keeps saying .selectpicker is not a function, although the file is included in twiddle.json

Answer (score 1):

In the line,

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => this.$().selectpicker());
```

`this` corresponds to the `Ember.Component`, Use `this.get('element')` to get the `select`.

```
$(this.get('element')).selectpicker()
```

And to provide class for a component : [Link](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names) . Just `class:'selectpicker'` used to work previously. Not sure if it will now.

UPDATE : 
Add this observer to your component and check,

```
    onChange : function(){
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender',this,function(){ 
            $(this.get('element')).selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    }.observes('opportunities'),
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. :/ Tried Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => $(this.get('element')).selectpicker()); and it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Nope. The problem is, it works 99%. When changing the selection on the dropdown it "selects" the correct opportunity, and even shows it as selected. Literally everything works except the text in the generated dropdown. I've added a screenshot to my question, and you can also check out the Twiddle (although I can't get selectpicker() to work at all in the Twiddle): ember-twiddle.com/5637ed5974e5d1e79906

Comment: The selectpicker you included is not being applied in that twiddle. Use this link  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/js/bootstrap-select.js . Now selectpicker is applied and i can see the proper html. But css is not applied properly. But anyway select picker is applied. Can you check?

Comment: http://ember-twiddle.com/996db20ed89945925797 .  Here is the edited twiddle. I just added bootstrap select js and css and it works. Seems your problem is not replicated here.

Comment: That seems to be the old Twiddle with `Uncaught TypeError: this.$(...).selectpicker is not a function` still happening?